# Cross-Origin Request Blocked when Fetching

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a express.js simple project:

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile("index.html",{root:__dirname})
})
app.listen(4000,()=>{console.log("started")})
```

And an index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script>
    const encodedParams = new URLSearchParams();
    encodedParams.append("url", "https://google.com/");

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'API_KEY',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com'
    },
    body: encodedParams
};

   fetch('https://url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com/shorten', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
</script>
</html>
```

So I am making a request to an API and It basically must work but it gives me this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com/shorten. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 451.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com/shorten. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use CORS in express
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

CORS allows you to load resources from different origins

Comment: I used app.use but it's still giving error. no diffrence

Comment: what browser are you using

Comment: Firefox Version 104

Comment: My edited code is this: app.use(cors())
app.get("/",cors(),(req,res,next)=>{
 res.sendFile("index.html",{root:__dirname})
})
app.listen(4000,()=>{})

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67861300/15492085
Try changing/checking this?

Comment: The request you're making actually comes from a 3rd party api. So it should have nothing to do with your server actually. Unless you are making other `fetch`requests that aren't shown here and they are giving you the same error.

Comment: My just-https setting in firefox is disabled and I not making any requests except this one.

Comment: Also, It doesn't fetch any url. It errors even when I fetch google

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247654/discussion-between-dozborne-and-mehan-alavi).