# Socket.io connection timing out, how to configure

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cors

We have a simple auction website with a form connected to the server with socket.io.

Admittedly, I'm not good with "server stuff" so getting this configured has been going on for weeks. I'm confused as to what the relevant symptoms are so some of this detail might be useless.

It's a basic form that submits a dollar amount to the server, which does stuff and emits a message that someone bid on the lot. All subscribed browsers simply refresh the form with new data. - all code works locally - The figures on the form update when a bid is received.

On the server - everything works perfectly on my system - also works for the other developer We got a call from a user (boss) on another network saying it doesn't work. He brought the same laptop here and the form works fine. I physically brought my laptop to that network and the form failed. It appears to be a CORS issue.

Firefox gives the `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource` error. That's confusing because the same browser didn't give that error on a different network. According to the docs, `curl "https://mydomaingoeshere.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"`  but on my "local" computer (the one that sockets "work" on) I get: `0{"sid":"994oKjjV0UmWZ0c3AAAH","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}` while the computer on the other network just times out for the same address.

I have tried disabling certification and rejections with this in my socket config  `requestCert: false, rejectUnauthorized: false` And it doesn't work, either.

This is the server...

```
require('dotenv').config(); 

var path = require('path'); 

var express = require('express');

 var fs = require('fs'); 

 var cors = require('cors'); 

 var app = express(); 
 app.use(cors()); // I have tried with and without this 

 var credentials = { 

     key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, process.env.PRIVATE_PATH)), 

     cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, process.env.CERT_PATH)), 

     ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, process.env.CA_PATH)), 

     requestCert: false, // tried adding to debug 

     rejectUnauthorized: false // tried adding to debug

}; 

var server = require('https').createServer(credentials, app); 

var io = require('socket.io')(server, 

    { cors: { 

        origin: "*", 

        methods: ["GET", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"] 

        } // this cors obj wasn't here, I tried this as a way to force it to work 

});

 // also tried this stuff from another thread... 

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); 

 app.use(function(req, res, next) { 

     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 

     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With"); 

     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); 

     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"); 

     next(); 

}); 

app.get('/', function (req, res) { 

    return res.send('server is running'); 

}); 

io.on('connection', function (socket) { 

    console.log('Welcome to server NodeJS'); 

    socket.on('send bid', function (response) { 

        var data = response.data;

        console.log(data); 

        io.sockets.emit('new bid', data);

    }); 

}); 

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

and this is the client

```
 socket = io.connect(socket_url); 

 socket.on("new bid", function (data) { 

     if (data.id === id) { 

         if (data.auction_close_time) { 

             clearInterval(master_timer); 

             initializeClock( "auction_clock", "live_auction", data.auction_close_time ); 

             refreshBiddingArea(data.id); 

             } 

        } 

    });
```

The only thing I can think of is the certificate. The socket server's certificate is not the same certificate as the one used by the website. The "demo" socket stuff I have was set up by someone else and I believe they used a let's encrypt cert for the socket server, which I've also done locally. I don't understand certs, so I'm not sure if this is related. It seems like I've set it up incorrectly but only on computers that don't have a local copy working already.

Note, some comments about things I've tried or am trying are in the code. Most of the CORS stuff is breadcrumbs of my efforts.

How do I go about configuring this connection to work consistently?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that much about it either. Could it possibly be a firewall issue? Have you tried from a third network (maybe from your phone while using mobile data)? I discovered an issue with my own socket app with mobile data. Turns out the production sockets just weren't reliable for me, and I had to be sure to provide more data for reconnection when necessary. Following this because I'm curious.

Comment: I thought maybe firewall but it has worked on that network at least once. It's gotta be configured wrong but I don't know how to debug the reason for failure, I just follow all the posts I can find and guess. I did try with mobile data and that worked fine.

Comment: If it gets solved I'll be sure to post the answer here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525595/cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the-remot This post indicates there may be a problem with firefox and self-signed certs. Could it be related?

Comment: Thanks! I think you're looking in the same area I am - it's not exactly the same problem but that is the error FF gives. Chrome/Edge give a different error. I do believe I have a self-signed cert just for the socket server. What I'm going to try now is pointing the socket server at the genuine cert and see if that even loads.

Comment: Random update, still no joy. I've tinkered to the point that I've found that on a slow connection, websocket stays pending indefinitely, and polling times out. Change the network connection and it works fine. This is the same on multiple computers.