# Restful-API node.js & expressCross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource s cat. Statuode: (null)

Tags: node.js, api, express, cors, restful-url

I created Restful API with node.js & express and when I moved API and website to server machine When I trying to open the website I receive error in console:

`Restful-API node.js & expressCross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource s cat. Statuode: (null).`

```
// Create express app
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var Pool = require('pg-pool')
var express = require("express")
var cors = require('cors')
var moment = require('moment');  

app.use(cors());
app.options('*',cors());

// Server port
var HTTP_PORT = 3010


const pool = new Pool(
  {
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: '192.168.0.1',
    user: 'usr',
    port: '3333',
    password: 'passwd',
    database: 'dbName',
  }
);

var floodguard_stations = '';


app.route('/stations')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    // omitted
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    //const id2 = req.query.id2;
    
    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM "maritsa_public"."maritsa_codenums";`, function (error, result_stations, fields) {
      if (error)
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Грешна заявка. Опитай отново !"})
      floodguard_stations = result_stations;
      res.json({ floodguard_stations })
    });
  });
```

The server it was uploaded to API have ssl. I call all URL links through the website with `https`://192.168.0.1:3333/stationsCan I get guidance on how to stop requests from being blocked?

Comment: Possible duplicate => https://stackoverflow.com/q/67525595/3057246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass * to specific domain in this line

from:

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

to:

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "paste your same domain here");

Comment: with https:// or only domain name ?

Comment: I trying like your answer but I still receive the same errors

Comment: with https:// in domain