How do i resolve the CORS error , while trying to connect my asp.net backend with Angular frontend?
This is my code. My API is working just fine, but CORS is not working.
using DatingApp.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowSpecificOrigins",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
                      });
});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString"));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigins"); // Use the named CORS policy

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have looked everywhere, I am not able to figure out what is wrong with this code.
It was expected that with CORS configured, my Angular frontend would be able to access the backend API. But there is an error somewhere

Considered that your project structure is different from the template of VS Angular and Asp.net Core, you need a generally applicable method. Your api cors code is correct, you need some modifications in your Angular module(default Asp.net Core WebApi as a sample).
create src/app/api.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  //Your api url and it should be https
  private apiUrl = 'https://localhost:7225/weatherforecast';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWeather(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, { withCredentials: true });
  }
}

src/app/app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="weatherData">
      <div *ngFor="let weather of weatherData">
        <p>{{ weather.date | date }}: {{ weather.summary }} ({{ weather.temperatureC }}°C)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  weatherData: any;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.getWeather().subscribe(data => {
      this.weatherData = data;
    });
  }
}

src/app/app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Without UseCors()

Cors configured


Its still not working .....

@Pinakss7 Then you could try to refer to this discussion about browser issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525595/cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the-remot though the status code is not the same. Also you can restart a new project and find the differences.
